# Plot function approximated by Newton interpolation not being displayed

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I am totally new to Mathematica and I was trying to compile this algorithm that is in our student's manual.
I tried different attempts also, but without any luck:

```
f[x_] = 3 Cos[2 x + 1] - 2 Sin[x/2 - 3]

g1 = Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi] }, PlotStyle -> Blue]
n =  16;
For[k = 1, k <= n, k++, r[k] = ((2. \[Pi])/n) k]
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
  DD[i + 1, i] = ( f[r[i + 1]] - f[r[i]])/(r[i + 1] - r[i])
  ];
For[j = 3, j <= n - 1, j++,
  For[i = 1, i < j - 1, i++,
   DD[j, j - i - 
      1] = (DD[j, j - i] - DD[j - 1, j - i - 1])/(r[i] - 
       r[j - i - 1])
   ]
  ];
p[x_] = f[r[1]] + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 2\), \(n\)]\(DD[k, 1] \(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Product]\), \(i = 1\), \(k - 1\)]\((x - 
        r[i])\)\)\)\);
g2 = Plot[p[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[g1, g2]
```

I believe it might be an older version mixed up with some typos.

Can anyone help me to have my first notebook (this one) to plot these functions?

Thank you.

[image: Student's manual screenshot]

Comment: What does "without any luck" mean for you?  I get two plots and some warnings.

Comment: On my screen when I click on evaluate notebook, nothing happens. I could manage to print a series of values, but not to plot these functions.
I have version 12. Also, I have the Mac version.

Comment: Closed the program, reopened it, it works.
Nonetheless, I would like to know if the for loops in the image are written correctly, as In some textbooks and example found online they are written as I mentioned in the code box. In short, the i++ part should come before "the what the loop should do" portion. Is that one in the picture an older syntax?
Thank you.

Comment: Anyways, the function g2 is not being plotted with red color but with blue.

Comment: You (and the author of the student's manual) should avoid the use of the `For` function.  Use `Do` or `Table` in *Mathematica*.  And it doesn't look like `g2` is working (which is why you don't see the color red).

Comment: The graph `g2`, which is supposed to plot the function `p[x]`, is not being plotted at all, presumably because of the division-by-zero errors.  The final output is only the graph `g1`.

Answer (score 1):

The code syntax in your screenshot is just plain wrong, and it has always been wrong.  Mathematica has always used the syntax

```
For[start,test,incr,body]
```

as can be seen in [the documentation for Mathematica 1.0 from 1988:](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v1/contents/2.5.2.pdf)
[image]

Comment: Given this error, I strongly suspect that the printed code was never tested;  and without more details on what the code is supposed to do, it is unlikely that anyone here will be able to fix it.

Comment: First of all, thank you all. So, long story short, in the mind of the author this was supposed to be an application of Newton's interpolation, following Weierstrass theorem, whereby any continuous function in the given closed interval [a,b] can be approximated, in a uniform way and a given precision, by a polynomial function.
Can you make a proper example of this or point me to a proper resource?
Basically I need to know the low level algorithm behind what Mathematica does for: 
https://imgur.com/qoGSb4l
Both with Lagrange and Newton

Comment: I want to point out that the goal of this course is not to become good at Mathematica, but to get the knowledge of the algorithms that can be used ALSO in Mathematica in order to write computer programs in any given language and apply them. So this is why I need the low level versions of the algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow-up**

The same professor posted a course on Youtube where he uses live the program and therefore some errors have been corrected.
I will leave it here in case someone is interested.

```
(*Interpolare lui Newton *)
Clear["`*"]
(*Luam in considerare o functie *)

f[x_] = 3 Cos[2 x + 1] - 4 Sin[x/2 - 3];

(*O reprezentam grafic intre 2 puncte: -5 si 5 *)
a = -5.;
b = 5.;
g1 = Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}, PlotStyle -> Blue]

(*Facem o esantionare a acestei functie intre un numar de puncte 
 Acesta esantionare se numeste echidistanta dar acesta nu este \
adevarat pentru orice functie.
*)
n = 15;
lst = {};
For[k = 0, k <= n, k++, 
  Subscript[r, k ] = ((b - a)/n k + a);
  AppendTo[lst, {Subscript[r, k ], f[Subscript[r, k]]}];
  ];
Print[lst];
g2 = ListPlot[lst, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]

(* Intre un cas concret noi nu cunoastem functia dar avem doar
o lista de puncte si incercam sa o determinam prin formula de \
interpolare lui Newton *)
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
  DD[i + 1, i] = (f[Subscript[r, i + 1 ]] - f[Subscript[r, i]])/(
    Subscript[r, i + 1 ] - Subscript[r, i ]);
  ];
For[j = 1, j <= n - 1, j++
    For[i = 1, i <= j - 2, i++, 
     DD[j, j - i - 1] = (DD[j, j - i] - DD[j - 1, j - i - 1])/(
       Subscript[r, j ] - Subscript[r, j - i - 1 ]);
     ];
  ];

p[x_] = f[Subscript[r, 1 ]] + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 2\), \(n\)]\(DD[k, \ 1]\ \(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Product]\), \(i = 1\), \(k - 1\)]\((x - 
\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(i\)])\)\)\)\);
Print["p(x)=", Expand[p[x]]];

g3 = Plot[p[x], {x, a, b}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[g1, g3, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> Style["Interpolare lui Newton"]]
Show[g1, g2, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> Style["Interpolare liniara"]]
(*Formula pentru a calcula eroarile care apar *)
Nr = 10 n;
For[i = 1, i <= Nr, i++, x[i] = (b - a)/Nr i + a];
e = 1/Nr \!\(\*
StyleBox[
UnderoverscriptBox["\[Sum]", 
RowBox[{"i", "=", "1"}], "Nr"],
FontSize->18]\*
SuperscriptBox[
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"f", "[", 
RowBox[{"x", "[", "i", "]"}], "]"}], "-", 
RowBox[{"p", "[", 
RowBox[{"x", "[", "i", "]"}], "]"}]}], ")"}],
FontSize->18], "2"]\)
```